# How can I disable mysql_native_password and mysql_old_password on MariaDB / MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I only want to use `unix_socket` as the sole authentication method.
Both `mysql_native_password` and `mysql_old_password` are installed and enabled by default, but I'd like to disable them.

I'm unable to uninstall them:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> uninstall plugin mysql_native_password;
ERROR 1619 (HY000): Built-in plugins cannot be deleted
```

I've followed the instructions here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_plugin/

I've created `disabled_plugins.ini` in `/etc/mysql` with contents:

```
disabled_plugins
mysql_old_password
```

Then:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> mysql_plugin disabled_plugins DISABLE;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql_plugin disabled_plugins DISABLE' at line 1
```

This is on WSL1 and 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log Debian 10

Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to run this command from server command line not from MariaDB console.

`mysql_plugin disabled_plugins DISABLE`

And then login to MariaDB & check :

`SELECT * FROM mysql.plugin;`

Comment: Thanks. I’m now getting the error `ERROR: No plugin specified.` After re-reading https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_plugin/ I went back and renamed the `.ini` file to `mysql_native_password` with a single line of `mysql_native_password`. 

The link says that the first line, should be the plugin name and the subsequent lines should be the components. But I’m not aware of any components here. So `$ mysql_plugin -p /etc/mysql/ -i mysql_native_password DISABLE` gives error `ERROR: No plugin specified.`

Comment: Login to mysql instance & fire this query ```SELECT * FROM mysql.plugin;```

Comment: Hi. This is what I'm getting: `MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT * FROM mysql.plugin;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Empty set (0.000 sec)`

Comment: this means there are no plugin installed in your instance. @NoExpert

Comment: But I can see the plugin. when I do `SHOW PLUGINS;` I can see: `| mysql_native_password         | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL    | GPL     |
| mysql_old_password            | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL    | GPL     |`